# ssh login to server pops the error " Bad : modifier in $ (/) "

Tags: ssh, environment-variables

I am trying to login to my remote machine (Fedora machine) from my local machine (Ubuntu 14.04).

I receive a typical error which seems related to setting of environment variables in my remote machine i.e.  `Bad : modifier in $ (/)`.

The entire debugging output of my ssh login is as follows:

```
praveer@praveer-HP-EliteBook-8460p:~$ ssh singhp@imagine2.enpc.fr -v

singhp@imagine2.enpc.fr's password: 

debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).

Authenticated to imagine2.enpc.fr ([195.221.193.65]:22).

debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]

debug1: Entering interactive session.

debug1: Sending environment.

debug1: Sending env LC_PAPER = fr_FR.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_ADDRESS = fr_FR.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_MONETARY = fr_FR.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_NUMERIC = fr_FR.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_TELEPHONE = fr_FR.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_IDENTIFICATION = fr_FR.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_MEASUREMENT = fr_FR.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_TIME = fr_FR.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_NAME = fr_FR.UTF-8

Last login: Thu May 25 13:34:38 2017 from ppp-seco21parth2-46-193-179-253.wb.wifirst.net

Bad : modifier in $ (/).
```

I know this problem is related to [Bad : modifier in $ (/)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40968061/bad-modifier-in) at the server end.

However how do I make sure that the setting of environment variables is done in a proper format at the remote machine while running the ssh command from my local machine                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 ?

Answer (score 0):

Fix the file on the server. After you `ssh` in to the server, show what your `.bashrc` is doing (and which particular line gives the error):

```
PS4='${BASH_SOURCE}:${LINENO} ' bash -x ~/.bashrc
```

Fix that line ON THE SERVER.